# How do I get summary statistics where I can decide the precision (number of digits) in R?

Tags: r, statistics

When I use

```
describe(combi$pca1)
```

from the `psych` package I get to few digits (values close to zero)

when I use `describeBy` also from the `psych` package it works by the subgroups

```
describeBy(combi$pca1, group=combi$realdeath, mat = TRUE, digits = 5)
```

However when I try to do it without group

```
describeBy(combi$pca1, mat = TRUE, digits = 5)
```

I got the error message:

> Error in matrix(NaN, ncol = ncol, nrow = n.var * n.groups) :
>     invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In describeBy(combi$pca1, mat = TRUE, digits = 5) :
>     no grouping variable requested

When I try to follow the documentation

```
describeBy(combi$pca1, group=NULL, mat = TRUE, digits = 5)
```

I got identical error message

> Error in matrix(NaN, ncol = ncol, nrow = n.var * n.groups) :
>     invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In describeBy(combi$pca1, group = NULL, mat = TRUE, digits = 5) :
>     no grouping variable requested

How can I get the desired precision of digits for the whole dataset without grouping?

Comment: @Frank What do You mean. describe is a part of the r psych package

Comment: I am guessing you have missing values, describeBy(combi$pca1, group=NULL, mat = TRUE, digits = 5, na.rm = TRUE) should do it

Comment: @Frank I got it :-)

Comment: @Dinesh.hmn  No it also returns:Error in matrix(NaN, ncol = ncol, nrow = n.var * n.groups) : 
  invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning message:
In describeBy(combi$pca1, group = NULL, mat = TRUE, digits = 5,  :
  no grouping variable requested

Comment: One hacky workaround is to make a "fake" grouping variable in your dataset that is a single value.

Comment: @aosmith Tx. That worked. It seems to be a ill behaving of describe which not can be handled by describeBy. Maybe a later version of describe will have a solution, but Your workaround were excellent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @aosmith the solution is the simple workaround to include a dummy group

which fools describeBy into believing that groups exist

combi@dummy <- 1
describeBy(combi$pca1, group= combi$dummy,mat=TRUE,digits=5)